# PHP não exibe aceita entrada de caracteres UTF-8 (caracteres acentuados) no modo interativo (REPL)

Tags: php, utf-8, acentuação, linha-de-comando

Estou tentando fazer o uso da linha de comando para fazer uma pequena alteração no servidor, a saber estou usando o PHP na linha de comando no modo interativo, porém percebi que o PHP não está aceitando caracteres acentuados.

Em ambiente local, funciona normalmente, porém quando logo no servidor da Amazon, simplesmente o PHP na linha de comando não aceita colocar letras acentuadas!

Eu já fiz o teste usando o Boris, Psysh e o próprio comando `php -a`. Todos estes rodam o PHP em modo interativo (REPL), mas não aceitam de forma alguma eu digitar caracteres acentuados. Quando eu digito, ou até mesmo tento colar, eles simplesmente não aparecem!

Alguém sabe o que pode fazer isso acontecer?

Comment: Qual a versão de PHP no server da Amazon? É diferente da versão instalada na sua máquina?

Comment: @Daniel a versão é `PHP 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) `

Comment: então... acho que você já encontrou o problema, né? "deprecated dontuse" é, literalmente, "não use essa versão".

Comment: @Daniel isso não é o problema, kkkk. Isso aí aconteceu por causa da troca do PPA, são problemas completamente diferentes. Quando instalei o PHP na época, não era depreciado :)

Comment: então, só perguntei por que às vezes é só um problema de versão mesmo. Se são a mesma nos dois não é isso. Mas acredito que o problema vai estar em alguma config lá no servidor mesmo.